# How to auto-push changes to git whenever a directory is changed

Tags: bash, git, inotify

I want my repo's local directory to essentially trigger a commit/push whenever any file in the directory has been changed.

I have looked into inotify-tools, specifically this command:

```
inotifywait -q -m -e CLOSE_WRITE --format="git commit -m 'auto commit' %w && git push origin <<branch>>" <<file>> | bash
```

but it looks like that is file-specific, whereas I want it listening for any change in any file in the local directory. Ideas?

Comment: sooo replace `<<file>>` with a directory?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I tried replacing <<file>> with a directory to no avail....

Comment: Not sure about `inotify`, but you could schedule a script to run at a particular frequency, which simply checks the repo status, and if there are changes, stage, commit, and push. You could even skip the check if you want, and just stage, commit, and push as often as you'd like (and sometimes nothing would happen).

Comment: You can't *just* replace the file name with a directory name, as the operations on directories are different. But you do want to get notifications about changes to directories. The details will depend on your inotify flavor (probably sufficiently standard on Linux now but there are differences on non-Linux systems). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-a-directory-for-creation-of-files-of-a-specific for more.

Answer (score 0):

a git script listens to changes if get any changes the auto-commit

```
cd /Users/[username]/[project-path]

while true; do
  changes=$(git diff --name-only HEAD)

  if [ ! -z "$changes" ]; then
    git add .

    timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)
    git commit -m "Auto-commit at $timestamp"

    git push origin
  fi

  sleep 5
done
```